# Using TypeScript decorators and promises with proper typing?

Tags: typescript, methods, promise, decorator, typing

I wrote a `buffered` decorator, which works as expected by returning a `Promise` (during the execution). However, to make the `tsc` transpiler happy, I'm forced to cast the decorated function with `any` and then (in the example below) with `Promise<number>`.

How can I avoid the extra casts? Is it even possible for a decorator to modify the signature of the decorated function? For example, how do I write an `@buffered` decorator, that takes a method function `f` (which returns `number`), while the decorated function `@buffered f` returns a `Promise<number>` (and *not* simply a `number`)?:

```
import { decorator as buffered } from '@dizmo/functions-buffered';

class Class {
    @buffered(100) // i.e. 100ms delay
    public f1(t: Date): number {
        return new Date().getTime() - t.getTime();
    }
    @buffered // i.e. defaults to 200ms delay
    public f2(t: Date): number {
        return new Date().getTime() - t.getTime();
    }
}

const p: Promise<number>
    = new Class().f1(new Date()) as any;

p.then((res: number) => { console.debug(res); });
```

I could write for example:

```
const p: Promise<number> = new Class().f1(new Date());
p.then((res: number) => { console.debug(res); });
```

However, then I get the following output:

```
[ts] Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Promise<number>'.
```

However, I should actually just be able to write:

```
const p = new Class().f1(new Date());
p.then((res: number) => { console.debug(res); });
```

But then `p` is recognized as a `number` instead of a `Promise`:

```
[ts] Property 'then' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

The implementation of the `@buffered` decorator is available at:

- https://github.com/dizmo/functions-buffered/blob/master/lib/index.ts

Please note that the implementation has additional complexity due to my desire to drop the parenthesis of the `@buffered` decorator, when I want to use a default delay of `200ms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorators can't change the structure of the class they are decorating. This is a design limitation. There is a proposal to [change this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) but it does not seem to be a priority (maybe upvote the GitHub issue  if it's important to you)

We could use a mapped type if we want to transform all methods, but we can't apply a mapped type transformation to only decorated properties so this is not a viable solution in this case.

A better option would be to actually have the corect return type directly in the class. We could do this with minimal changes to the code using `async`:

```
class Class {
    @buffered(100) // i.e. 100ms delay
    // use async and return a promise instead of a number
    public async f1(t: Date): Promise<number> {
        return new Date().getTime() - t.getTime();
    }
    @buffered // i.e. defaults to 200ms delay
    public async f2(t: Date) { // no need to specify the return type will be inferred correctly to Promise<number>
        return new Date().getTime() - t.getTime();
    }
}

const p: Promise<number> = new Class().f1(new Date()); // works fine

p.then((res: number) => { console.debug(res); });
```

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881

Comment: @jcalz 10x for the link :)